# Compare two lists for similarity in Elixir

Tags: list, elixir

I have two lists of skills that I’d like to compare to provide a percentage score for how much of one list appears in the other:

```
user_skills = [
  %{name: "Elixir"}, 
  %{name: "Python"}
]

project_skills = [
  %{name: "Elixir"}, 
  %{name: "Erlang"}, 
  %{name: "Ruby"}
]
```

What percentage of `user_skills` appear in `project_skills`? What we’d want here is a result of `50%`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can be very simple and use [Kernel.--/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#--/2) to calculate the difference first:

```
iex(5)> user_skills -- project_skills
# [%{name: "Python"}]
```

You can then use the length of the original list `user_skills` and the length of the above operation to get a percentage like figure:

```
iex(6)> 1 - (length(user_skills -- project_skills) / length(user_skills))
0.5
```

If you'd like to do more sophisticated comparisons and diffs, take a look at the [myers_difference](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#myers_difference/2) as well.

Comment: You'd want to subtract the result from 1 to get the percentage. If user_skills is "HTML" "CSS", it would return 1, given this code. Also "Elixir" & "Ruby" would return 0.